# Torch installation issue: module 'torchcwrap' not found

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, torch

I am facing a installation issue with reference to the [Torch installation guide](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_) on an Ubuntu14.04 machine.
After the git-clone of torch package, torch was installed to my home folder in `~/torch` by running:

```
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
TORCH_LUA_VERSION=LUA51 ./install.sh
```

Part of the terminal output is posted as follow:

```
/home/fit/torch/install/bin/lua: /home/fit/torch/pkg/torch/random.lua:3: module 'torchcwrap' not found:
no field package.preload['torchcwrap']

no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.lua'

no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap/init.lua'

no file '/home/fit/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.lua'

no file '/home/fit/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap/init.lua'

no file '/home/fit/deeptracking/deeptracking/tracker/torchcwrap.lua'

no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.so'

no file '/home/fit/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.so'

no file './torchcwrap.so'

no file '/home/fit/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:

[C]: in function 'require'

/home/fit/torch/pkg/torch/random.lua:3: in main chunk

[C]: ?

make[2]: *** [random.c] Error 1

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 /home/fit/torch/install/bin/lua:      /home/fit/torch/pkg/torch/TensorMath.lua:3: module 'torchcwrap' not found:

 no field package.preload['torchcwrap']

 no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.lua'

 no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap/init.lua'

 no file '/home/fit/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.lua'

 no file '/home/fit/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torchcwrap/init.lua'

 no file '/home/fit/deeptracking/deeptracking/tracker/torchcwrap.lua'

 no file '/home/fit/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.so'

 no file '/home/fit/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/torchcwrap.so'

 no file './torchcwrap.so'

 no file '/home/fit/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
 stack traceback:

[C]: in function 'require'

/home/fit/torch/pkg/torch/TensorMath.lua:3: in main chunk

[C]: ?

make[2]: *** [TensorMath.c] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/torch.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] 
Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a similar issue posted [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/1007). After adding ';./?.lua;' to the LUA_PATH variable, subsequent instrallation works well.